# forms on web2py using AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, web2py

Hello so I am trying to have the user enter in some fields in the view and then it be send at POST data using AJAX to the controller where I insert it into the db. It tends to only work for 1 field which is des_location but for the others I get an error. Here is my code.

VIEW:

```
<div id="target"></div>
<div id="iter_body" name="iter_body" title="body for iter">

<form id="form_one">
<h4>Itinerary Name:<h4>
<input name="d_name" id="d_name" /><br>
<h4>Location:<h4>
<input name="d_location" id="d_location" /><br>
<h4>Date Started:<h4>
<input name="d_date_start" id="d_date_start" type="date"><br>
<input name="post_button" type="submit" value="POST!" />
</form>
<!--<button type="button" id="post_button2" value="Post Data" onclick="PostIt()">Post!</button> --> 
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery('#form_one').submit(function()
  {
    ajax('{{=URL('do_stuff')}}',['d_name','d_location'], 'target'); 
    return false;
  });
</script>


</div>
```

Controller:

```
def do_stuff():
    form = SQLFORM(db.all_itinerary)    
    print "I at least get into this function 23"
    #if form.accepts(request, formname=None):
    if request.vars.d_name:
        print "testing2"
        db.all_itinerary.insert(it_name=request.vars.d_name)
    if request.vars.d_location:
        print "testing"
        db.all_itinerary.insert(des_location=request.vars.d_location)
    if request.vars.d_date_start:
        db.all_itinerary.insert(days_staying_start=request.vars.d_date_start)    
        print "what happens here?"
        return DIV("WORKS")
    elif form.errors:
        print "what happens here 2?"
        return TABLE(*[TR(k, v) for k, v in form.errors.items()])
```

MODEL:

```
db.define_table('all_itinerary',
               Field('it_name'),
               Field('des_location'),#, 'reference des'),
#leave des_location as a string for now and then update it to ref after des tables are all set up               
                Field('days_staying_start', 'date'),
               #Field('days_staying_end', 'date'),
                #Field('des_description_of_stays', 'text')
               )
```

anyone know whats going on??

Comment: Can you explain what you are expecting and what you are observing instead? It looks like your code currently inserts two separate records, one with an it_name but no des_location, and one with a des_location but no it_name. Were you instead aiming to insert a single record?

Comment: I wanted all records to be added but for some reason only one get passed through from the ajax call.

Comment: What error do you get (is there a traceback)? Which of your print statements are executed? How are you determining what gets inserted (are you looking in appadmin immediately after the submission)? Using the browser tools, can you see what data are sent via the Ajax call?